# Getting 401 for Spring Boot API after login to keycloak.But its work if user didn't sign in to keycloak

Tags: spring-boot, security, keycloak

I'm using **Spring Boot + Keycloak + Angular** for my application and keycloak-spring-boot-starter uses for the backend. But this is working perfectly on my computer and when I deploy this

- Without logging to the system system works perfectly
- When login to the system using angular app and make a api request getting 401 from Spring boot backend
- In postman without token it gives results
- In postman with the token it gives 401

But on angular side (frontend) Authentification and Authorization work perfectly. Further, I have tried to run this application in the machine(angular and Spring boot run in my local machine similar environment to production) using deployed keycloak, it also works perfectly.

Since there is no related error in the console I'm really worried about how to figure out the issue. I'm kindly requesting you to help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it was my mistake I have set SSL to `none` in Keycloak configuration but Spring Boot app I have set to `external`. Therefore it works on my computer and when I deploy it, it didn't work.